# Rails: How to use facets with search results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, search, facet, faceted-search

I have a rails application where I am searching for repair shops. The search class method looks like this:

```
def self.search(params)
        if params
            repairshop = Repairshop.where(:approved => true)

            if params[:radius].present?
                repairshop = repairshop.near(params[:location], params[:radius]) if params[:location].present?
            else
                repairshop = repairshop.near(params[:location], 200) if params[:location].present?              
            end

            if params[:keywords].present?
                repairshop = repairshop.joins(:specializations).joins(:brands_we_services).where("LOWER(specializations.title) LIKE ? OR LOWER(brands_we_services.title) LIKE ? OR LOWER(repairshop.title) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:keywords].downcase}%", "%#{params[:keywords].downcase}%", "%#{params[:keywords].downcase}%")
            end

            repairshop.uniq
        else
            all
        end

    end
```

A repair shop can have many specializations and brands_we_services. So, searching through all of the names apart form other params is important.

The search form looks like this:
[image]

Everything works fine. And the search controller takes me to the search page. The controller action is as follows:

```
def search
        @repairshops = Repairshop.search(params)
end
```

The search result looks like this:

[image]

**My question is:**

On the left side of the search page, below the search box, I want to provide facets for filtering the results. I want to provide facets which would be dynamic. Like depending on Search results, it provides facets for cities (number of repair shops) etc.

I don't want to use elastic search or solr. **I want to understand how I build dynamic faceted search from scratch, the basics of building facets from your search results**.

Note: I looked into Forty facets but couldn't understand how can I use my complex class method search which is in Repairshop model and integrate it into the `class MovieSearch < FortyFacets::FacetSearch` provided by the controller as per the docs.

Will really appreciate your help. Thanks!